# $X$ is standard normal if $X=Y1_{\{|Y|\le a\}}-Y1_{\{|Y|>a\}}$ where $Y$ is standard normal

Tags: probability, random-variables

$X$ is standard normal if $X=Y1_{\{|Y|\le a\}}-Y1_{\{|Y|>a\}}$ where $Y$ is standard normal.

$$F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=P(\{Y\le x\}\cap\{|Y|\le a\})+P(\{-Y\le x\}\cap\{|Y|> a\})$$

How can I simplify from here, i.e. do I take the min of $x$ and $a$ in the first probability?

Comment: You need "$\cap$" where you have "$\cup$".

Comment: right, sorry i typed cup instead of cap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $-a<x<a$ then
\begin{align}
F_X(x)=P(X\le x) & =P(\{Y\le x\}\cap\{|Y|\le a\})+P(\{-Y\le x\}\cap\{|Y|> a\}) \\[8pt]
& = P(-a<Y<x) + P(Y<-a) \\[8pt]
& = P(Y<x) = \Phi(x).
\end{align}

If $x>a$ then
\begin{align}
F_X(x)=P(X\le x) & =P(\{Y\le x\}\cap\{|Y|\le a\})+P(\{-Y\le x\}\cap\{|Y|> a\}) \\[8pt]
& = P(-a<-Y<a) + P(-Y<x\ \&\ Y\not\in(-a,a)) \\[8pt]
& = P(-Y<x) = \Phi(x).
\end{align}

Now do a similar thing with $x<-a$.

In each case you get $F_X(x)=\Phi(x)$.

Unfortunately some things have to get done piecewise.

An example like this can show that a pair $(X,Y)$ can fail to be independent even though each component is normal and they are uncorrelated.  If the value of $a$ is just the right number, then these are uncorrelated.  That doesn't happen if $X$, $Y$ are *jointly* normal.

Comment: thanks so much! this is so clear and helpful